# Set android focus on touch?

Tags: android, keyboard, focus, android-edittext

I have this issue: in my app, when user taps on EditText bar, keyboard pops up. After that, it is impossible to get rid of keyboard. When back button is pressed, whole application just turn off.
How can I make sure, that when user taps on some other object (not EditText), keyboard will be removed? Or at least, how to make it possible to hide keyboard by tapping back button?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in xml for EditText this will make keyboard dismiss when press enter on keyboard

```
 android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Comment: Yes, but now, when I press enter, data is not being received by app. I need to press on edittext again, in order to to send data.

Comment: how are you getting the data from the EditText?

Comment: Basically, my EditText inputYype is "text". When user inputs some sort of keyword (this edittext window is used for inputting keyword for search) and pushes "done" (blue button), then search results are printed out.

Comment: if you use TextWatcher right when you put the text into the editText it will automatically update the string or whatever your using to use the information from the edittext

Comment: Great, now I have another question. While I am typing keyword, results are being calculated - this really slows down my phone. How to make sure, that results will only be calculated after i press enter button.

Comment: use an onKeyListener and check when enter button is pressed actually get the text from the edittext

Comment: I managed to setOnKeyListener, keyboard now hides when I press it, but because of android:imeOptions="actionDone" -  app is Unable to get data. TextWatcher is not an answer, since for my app, it is pretty much useless. There has got to be a better way.

Comment: do you have enter button in if statement and in block getting information from edittext in onkeylistener?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the keyboard simple by overriding `onBackPressed` in your Activity and using the following code:

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(anyView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Note that **anyView** can be any view that is attached to your current window.

You can see it working in my app called *[Magic Annotator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nbempire.android.magicannotator)*. See method [hideSoftKeyboard()](https://github.com/barriosnahuel/magicAnnotator/blob/master/src/main/java/com/nbempire/android/magicannotator/util/android/view/ScoreEditorView.java)

Comment: Thank you for sharing source code :) This really helps. However, now, when i touch edittext box, keyboard doesn't pop up again.

Comment: I don't know what to say, I tried again that usage and it works. Maybe I'm doing something extra different, then you should see my code and look for something else. Sorry!